# I want to populate the list with some user-defined values and eventually print the list. What will be the main()

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I want the corresponding `main()` to implement this code along with explanation. I'm trying to populate the linked list just like an array and eventually printing the elements within this list.

I'm new to Data structures and want to get the concept very clearly and in Java. Any help will be highly appreciated.

My code:

```
public class LinkedList {
    private LinkedList next; //just creating getters and setters for the next node
    private int data; //just creating getters and setters for the data
    public LinkedList(int data) {
        this.data=data; //default constructor to input a value to the node
    }
    public LinkedList getNext() {
        return next; //getter method for the object (probably returns the value of the address of the current object) 
    }
    public void setNext(LinkedList next) {
        this.next = next; //setter method for the object (probably to set the address of the next node)
    }
    public int getData() {
        return data; //getter method for the data (probably to get the data of the current node)
    }
    public void setData(int data) {
    this.data = data;//setter method for the data (probably to set the data in the current node)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dummy sample that you should now improve :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // populate from array
    int[] data = {1,2,3};
    LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(0);
    LinkedList l = myList;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
        l.setData(data[i]);
        if (i == data.length - 1) continue;
        l.setNext(new LinkedList(0));
        l = l.getNext();
    }

    // print
    l = myList;
    while(l != null) {
         System.out.print(l.getData() + ",");
         l = l.getNext();
    }
}
```